# white-space: nowrap and overflow:hidden within table cell

Tags: css, html-table, overflow

I'm building a calendar. I have a table where each `<td>` is a day. I want to display a list of events for that day within the cell. I want each event to appear as two lines of text, if the text is longer than there is horizontal space for then the text should be hidden.

I have a table that has a variable width (it's set to `width: 100%;` of its parent elsewhere in my CSS).

Here's my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fZGyz/1/

The problem you can see is that despite `width: 100%;` and `overflow: hidden;` being explicitly set, the text of `.eventSummary` and `.eventLocation` is forcing the table to expand, which is not what I want.

Is this one of those "not currently possible" problems in CSS?

UPDATE:

I can hack it with `table-layout: fixed;` and setting `overflow: hidden;` on the `<td>`... it'll do for now (as there's no ellipsis, and any border-right on the `<li>` would be hidden, so the original problem still stands.

Answer (score 0):

It's expanding because the width is set to 100% of its parent (which is the body of the document). So the table expands to fit its children. Either put the table in a div that has a fixed width or fix the width of the table.

Answer (score 0):

All your values are relative, which brings expanding. Try to set needed max-width for `.eventSummary` and `.eventLocation` and don't forget to set display: block for them.